# Kähler differentials and genus

Tags: algebraic-geometry

What is the relation between the dimension of the space of Kähler differentials of a projective curve and the genus of the curve?

Comment: Via Riemann-Roch.

Comment: I guess I know the "wrong" version of R-R... (I know the version for rational functions). Can you point me to the "good" version.

Answer (score 2):

As QiL pointed out, you can use Riemann-Roch on a curve $C$ with $L=\mathcal O_C$ to get that $l(K_C)=g-1$, where $g=g(C)$ is the genus of the curve.  But you don't really need R-R to see that.  The geometric genus of the curve is defined to be $h^0(C,\mathcal O_C(K_C))$ which is exactly the dimension of the vector space of Kähler differentials on $C$.  The arithmetic genus of the curve is defined to be $h^1(C,\mathcal O_C)$, and in the case of a curve these are the same by Serre duality.  Here $l(K_C)=h^0(C,\mathcal O_C(K_C)) - 1$ by definition, which is the dimension of the projective space of Kähler forms.